# How to create Mac OS X docker image?

Tags: macos, docker

I am new to the docker. I need to create Mac OS X docker image.
is it possible? if Yes, How to create Mac OS X docker image?

Answer (score 1):

Docker provides methods for managing OS-level containers and is built on top of Linux's native features for OS-level containerization. All containers running on a system share the same kernel; Mac OS X does not use the Linux kernel, but rather a mach kernel, so it cannot be run inside a Docker container at this time.

You can run Docker on your Mac but containers running on that instance would need to run Linux.